# JQ: Select objects with key's value in set of values

Tags: jq

I have an array of json objects and I would like to extract a subset of the array such that the `.name` field matches a set of input strings.

for example I would like to accomplish the following.

```
jq -n '["a","b","c","d","e"] | map({name:.,foo:"bar"})' \
  | jq 'map(select(.name=="a" or .name=="c"))'
```

I've come up with the following solution, but my usage of `[...]` and `add` seems like I am missing something clever.

```
jq -n '["a","b","c","d","e"] | map({name:.,foo:"bar"})' \
  | jq --arg name 'a c' '
      [
        ( $name | split(" ") )[] as $name
        | map( select( .name == $name ) )
        | add
      ]'
```

Also, this solution forces me to iterate over the input array multiple times instead of a single pass. Any other ideas how I could solve this?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Move everything into the `select` condition.  You don't need to do two separate calls to jq.

```
$ echo '["a","b","c","d","e"]' | jq --arg names 'a c'
    'map(select(. == ($names | split(" ")[])) | { name: ., foo: "bar" })'
[
  {
    "name": "a",
    "foo": "bar"
  },
  {
    "name": "c",
    "foo": "bar"
  }
]
```

Comment: I was using the first jq to generate a sample input in the array of object format I was parsing...  Your answer is completely correct just indexing slightly different. `map(select(.name==($names|split(" ")[])))`

Comment: I ask, can you please breakdown the syntax elements? I cant comprehend what this perl-esqe series of special characters is trying to accomplish  <3

Answer (score 2):

To [ThorSummoner](https://stackoverflow.com/users/1695680/thorsummoner)'s point,
here is a less perl-esqe solution that uses **--argjson** and **inside** with
comments on separate lines that takes advantage of shell `'` behavior:

```
$ echo '["a","b","c","d","e"]' | jq --argjson wanted '["a","c"]' '
  .[]                          # break array into elements
| if ([.]|inside($wanted))     # if element is in wanted
  then {name: ., foo:"bar"}    # generate desired output
  else empty                   # otherwise generate nothing
  end
'
```