# Values from array foo not in array bar

Tags: jq

I'm trying to filter an array with another.
For example, given I have this input array:
`['foo', bar', 'baz']`
And this filter array:
`['foo', 'baz']`

I want to have this output:
`['bar']`

I feel like I could be able to do this by piping to `select(inside())`, but I can't get `inside()` to work; I get a "not defined" error.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use the convenient subtraction operator `-` as follows:

```
jq '. - ["foo", "baz"]'
```

Comment: What if I wanted to do for values in an object instead? i.e.
`[{"key": "foo"},{"key": "bar"},{"key": "baz"}]`
I only really care about the values themselves, so I tried doing:
`.[].key - ["foo", "baz"]` but that doesn't work.

Comment: @nVitius: That's a completely different question all together. You stated that the input array is of strings, not objects. Either way, [that question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/26701538) ([and](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/29659436) [its](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/25649960) [variations](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/29518137)) was already answered.

Comment: Yeah, it is. Thanks for the links to the other questions.